# Merging multiple dataframes based on daterange

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

- I have this data

  ```
  id<-c("1","3")
  Outcome<-c("Balanced","Balanced")  
  FromDate<-as.Date(c("2016-01-01","2016-01-01"),'%Y-%m-%d')
  ToDate<-as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-01-01"),'%Y-%m-%d')
  type<-c("ccc")
  data<-data.frame(id,Outcome,FromDate,ToDate,type) 
  R> data

     id  Outcome    FromDate     ToDate     type  

     1   Balanced   2016-01-01   2017-01-01  ccc  
     3   Balanced   2016-01-01   2017-01-01  ccc

  refno<-c("1","2","1","1")
  sedolnumber<-c("ABC123","XYZ12","ABC123","ZZZ123") 
  order_placement_date<-as.Date(c("2016-02-01","2017-02-05","2017-02-01","2016-04-01"),'%Y-%m-%d')
  units_buyed<-c("1000","200","1000","1000")
  buy<-data.frame(refno,sedolnumber,order_placement_date,units_buyed)

  R> buy   
  refno sedolnumber order_placement_date units_buyed
     1      ABC123           2016-02-01        1000
     2       XYZ12           2017-02-05         200
     1      ABC123           2017-02-01        1000
     1      ZZZ123           2016-04-01        1000

  refno<-c("1","1")
  sedolnumber<-c("ABC123","ABC123") 
  sell_placement_date<-as.Date(c("2016-05-01","2017-05-01"),'%Y-%m-%d')
  units_sold<-c("500","500")
  sell<-data.frame(refno,sedolnumber,sell_placement_date,units_sold)

  R> sell   
  refno sedolnumber sell_placement_date units_sold
    1      ABC123          2016-05-01        500  
    1      ABC123          2017-05-01        500
  ```
- I want to join all three tables based on the conditions and add one more columns **Units_Retained** which would be subtraction of columns buy.units_buyed-sell.units_sold:

  1. data.id=buy.refno
  2. buy.order_placement_date >= data.FromDate AND buy.order_placement_date < data.ToDate
  3. data.id=sell.refno
  4. buy.sedolnumber=sell.sedolnumber
  5. sell.sell_placement_date >= data.FromDate AND sell.sell_placement_date < data.ToDate
- Units retained columns should show value of **units_buyed** if units_sold is null and **0** if both units_buyed and units_sold are null
- I am doing this with sqldf package. Are there any functions in R to achieve this without using sqldf. *data* table is my parent table and should show blank values if the matching records in buy and sell tables are not found.

  ```
  R>sqldf("SELECT a.id,a.outcome,a.FromDate,a.ToDate,a.type,b.sedolnumber,b.order_placement_date,b.units_buyed,c.units_sold,c.sell_placement_date,(b.units_buyed-c.units_sold) as Units_Retained 
   FROM data a LEFT JOIN buy b ON (a.id=b.refno AND b.order_placement_date>=a.FromDate AND b.order_placement_date<a.ToDate) 
   LEFT JOIN sell c ON(a.id=c.refno AND c.sell_placement_date>=a.FromDate AND c.sell_placement_date<a.ToDate AND b.sedolnumber=c.sedolnumber)  ") 



  R>  id  Outcome   FromDate     ToDate   type sedolnumber order_placement_date units_buyed units_sold sell_placement_date Units_Retained
      1    Balanced 2016-01-01 2017-01-01  ccc      ABC123           2016-02-01        1000        500          2016-05-01            500
      1    Balanced 2016-01-01 2017-01-01  ccc      ZZZ123           2016-04-01        1000       <NA>                <NA>             NA
      3    Balanced 2016-01-01 2017-01-01  ccc        <NA>                 <NA>        <NA>       <NA>                <NA>             NA
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` verbs

```
library(dplyr)

get_units_retained <- function(units_buyed, units_sold) {

  units_buyed <- as.numeric(as.character(units_buyed))
  units_sold <- as.numeric(as.character(units_sold))

  if_else(is.na(units_buyed), 0, units_buyed) - if_else(is.na(units_sold), 0, units_sold)

}


left_join(data, buy, by = c("id" = "refno")) %>% 
  left_join(sell, by = c("id" = "refno", "sedolnumber")) %>% 
  filter(
      (order_placement_date >= FromDate & order_placement_date < ToDate) | is.na(order_placement_date), 
      (sell_placement_date >= FromDate & sell_placement_date < ToDate) | is.na(sell_placement_date)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Units_Retained = get_units_retained(units_buyed, units_sold))
```

Comment: Is it possible to subtract null values too? Units retained columns should show value of units_buyed if units_sold is null and 0 if both units_buyed and units_sold are null. @amarchin

Comment: Now it should works. But based on what you write in the previous comment the result you show in the question is wrong ;)

Comment: Yes i couldn't reproduce the output using IFNULL as it isn't supported by sqldf. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table` if you operate with a really large data :

```
require(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
buy <- as.data.table(buy)
sell <- as.data.table(sell)
setkey(data,id)
setkey(buy,refno)
setkey(sell,refno,sedolnumber)
dd <- setkey(data[buy,nomatch = 0],
       id,
       sedolnumber
       )[
         sell,nomatch = 0
         ][
           order_placement_date >= FromDate &  order_placement_date < ToDate &
             sell_placement_date >= FromDate & sell_placement_date < ToDate,
           ][,
             Units_Retained := as.numeric(as.character(units_buyed)) - as.numeric(as.character(units_sold))
             ]
```

Comment: Please check my updated question lost my internet connection so couldn't update it for a long time @Alex